# I need to get the sum of all the odd values in odd columns

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array printing out only odd columns, and need to get the sum of all the odd values in odd columns. I create the variable total to do this and set it equal to 0 and then did total+= table[c][r]; but this is printing out 0.

How do I fix this?

```
class oddArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int table[][] = new int [10][10];
        for (int r=0; r<table.length; r++) {
            int total = 0;
            for (int c=1; c<=table[r].length; c+=2) {
                System.out.printf(r*c+"\t");
                table[r][c] = r + c;
                total+= table[r][c];
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(total);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never put any values in your `table` array, so it contains only 0s by default. Hence the total is 0.

You have other problems in your code though :

1. Your inner loop's condition should be `c < table[r].length` (though in your specific case of 10x10 array it makes no difference).
2. You should be adding `table[r][c]` to the total, not `table[c][r]`.

Comment: Made the correction for 1 & 2. When insert values into my table would i have to insert 100 values to fill each position since it's a 10x10 array?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava like so?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your columns loop should go to `< table[r].length` instead of `<=`.
2. If you need to calculate the total of all elements in all the **odd** values of odd columns, then you should check if the element is odd or not before adding it to `total`.
3. Your current program prints the total of elements of each column separately. I understand that you need to

> get the sum of all the odd values in odd columns.

For this, you should not reinitialize your total every time you enter the `row` loop, instead you should initialize it at the beginning of the program and then keep adding the odd elements in the inner loop, eg, like this:

```
if (table[r][c] & 1 == 1)  //check if element is odd
    total += table[r][c];
```

Answer (score 0):

A table with 10 columns only has indexes between 0 and 9.

This means that you will *almost never* iterate while less than or equal the length of an array.  You will probably just iterate up to less than the length of an array.